# Passing closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I have a function that I've been using in my code, but I need to pass a completion handler to it now (so I can exit a dispatch_group). I didn't want it to effect the rest of my code so I tried changing the namespace from this:

```
func uploadRecordable<T: Recordable>(instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase)
```

to this:

```
func uploadRecordable<T: Recordable>(instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (())? = nil)
```

When I go to pass a closure to it like so:

```
cloud.uploadRecordable(testRecordable, database: database) {
        dispatch_group_leave(forCloudToBeClearOfTestRecord)
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Function produces expected type 'Void' (aka '()'); did you mean to call it with '()'?
```

I think that because the `completionHandler: (())?` argument has a default value of `nil` the compiler is confused by the closure, but when I tried this I still get same error:

```
    cloud.uploadRecordable(testRecordable, database: database, completionHandler: {
        dispatch_group_leave(forCloudToBeClearOfTestRecord)
    })
```

I haven't passed a lot of closures, so I could be doing it wrong, but `(())?` has worked for me in the past... Also, if it makes any difference this is being called in my tests not my regular code.

Any help on what I'm missing here?

**-EDIT-**

After changing the closure argument to `(() -> ())?` I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke `uploadRecordable` with an argument list of type '(MockRecordable?, database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (() -> ())?)'
```

The first two arguments have been working fine, but it doesn't like my closure still. Should I be putting something on the first line (e.g. `var in`) even though I'm not giving it any variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. Why wouldn't I want it to return Void, for my own edification?

Comment: I'm making a follow up edit shortly.

Comment: Regarding the new error, you're passing an optional `MockRecordable` as the first parameter. Perhaps you should unwrap that?

Comment: That was it! I'm such a moron. If you want to post as an answer I can check mark it for you. Thanks @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function declaration, rather than declaring the parameter as `completionHandler: (())?`, you want `completionHandler: (() -> Void)?` or `completionHandler: (() -> ())?`.

Thus:

```
func uploadRecordable<T: Recordable>(instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil) { ... }
```

Or

```
func uploadRecordable<T: Recordable>(instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (() -> ())? = nil) { ... }
```